# What does the -r option do when using wget?

Tags: command-line, wget

I am having trouble understanding what exactly the `-r` option does when using wget. The man page says that it'll `Turn on recursive retrieving.    The default maximum depth is 5.`
What exactly is meant by "recursive retrieving"? When I tried not including `-r` I just get a `.tmp` file, and nothing else would download

Comment: This Seems pretty through...It does not to you? https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html

Comment: @EODCraftStaff as a web developer, I find it very ambiguous; does it download the target HTML in anchor tags? or does it mean JS/CSS? What about the href target in img tags? What about external fonts references by CSS? Does it allow you to store a local version of a webpage? What's the function/use case of it? The problem is that there's no such thing as "folders" on the web; it's not a filesystem with hierarchy — the server receives a URL and returns a response. What is meant by "recursive" here exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In a simplified way `-r` will retrieve your page first, then it will parse your page, extract the links and retrieve them one by one "level 1". Then it will extract all links from the "level 1" pages and will download those as well ("level 2"), but it will not download again the pages already downloaded. And so on and so forth. I usually use it with `-np` option, which prevents downloading from parent pages.